# Python function to iterate over a column and calculate the forumla

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a data set like this :

```
YEAR  MONTH VALUE 
2018   3    59.507
2018   3    26.03
2018   5    6.489
2018   2    -3.181
```

i am trying to perform a calculation like 
((VALUE1 + 1) * (VALUE2 + 1) * (VALUE3+1).. * (VALUEn +1)-1) over VALUE column

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['VALUE'].add(1).prod()-1
#-26714.522733572892
```

---

If you want cumulative product to create a new column use [`Series.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
df['new_column']=df['VALUE'].add(1).cumprod().sub(1)
print(df)

   YEAR  MONTH   VALUE    new_column
0  2018      3  59.507     59.507000
1  2018      3  26.030   1634.504210
2  2018      5   6.489  12247.291029
3  2018      2  -3.181 -26714.522734
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after...

```
cum_prod = (1 + df['VALUE'].cumprod()) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand the objects you're dealing with, what attributes and methods they have. This is a Dataframe and the Value column is a Series.

here is the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html